# Removing all classes in a container with javascript

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, class, vuejs2

I'm trying to remove all the classes inside a parent element, the structure looks like the following

```
<div id="middleCol">
  <section class="toggleSection" id="step1" v-on:click="toggleStep($event)" ref="step1">
    <small>Step 1</small>
    <h5>Flight Details</h5>
  </section>

  <section class="toggleSection"  id="step2" v-on:click="toggleStep($event)" ref="step2">
    <small>Step 2</small>
    <h5>Traveler Info</h5>
  </section>

  <section class="toggleSection"  id="step3" v-on:click="toggleStep($event)" ref="step3" >
    <small>Step 3</small>
    <h5>Payment</h5>
  </section>
</div>
```

basically these are tabs and I only want to apply an active class to one div at a time, my plan is to remove all classes then add the active class to whatever tab is clicked using an event but I'm getting an error that the className property on the other child elements doesn't exist, the function works to add classes just not to remove them, I have seen a few jquery solutions but I was hoping to find a vanilla one

any help is appreciated :)

here is the function I am trying to use

```
function toggleActive(event){
  let element = event.currentTarget
  let parent = element.parentNode.children;
  console.log(element)
  console.log(parent)
           
  for (let child in parent){
    parent[child.value].className = ''
  }
  element.classList.add("toggleSectionActive");
}
```

Comment: There are no classes in the structure you're showing, though. It'd be better to show an example of what you'd start with, and what you'd like to end up with, with the code that you already wrote to try to achieve that.

Comment: thanks, I have updated with a snippet of the relevant vue template code I'm using

Comment: if you are using Vue I'd suggest to use Vue's classes binding and let Vue decide which classes to use for each section instead of changing them manually https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html, they even show the example of an `isActive` class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to to bind class and use v-for for sections:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data(){
    return {
      toggled: 0,
      sections: [
        {id: 0, name: 'Step 1', desc: 'Flight Details'},
        {id: 1, name: 'Step 2', desc: 'Traveler Info'},
        {id: 2, name: 'Step 3', desc: 'Payment'}
      ]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    toggleStep(id){
      this.toggled = id
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <div id="middleCol">
    <section :class="section.id === toggled && 'active'" v-for="section in sections" :key="section.id" @click="toggleStep(section.id)">
      <small>{{ section.name }}</small>
      <h5>{{ section.desc }}</h5>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, this broke it down for me :) I was following the vbind examples trying to figure it out thanks for laying out the proper demo for me